# How to change background-color of LayoutAnimation?

Tags: react-native

I have a view which can be disappeared by clicking a button. Before I "remove" the View I set this:

```
LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
```

The animation works fine, but the Animation is always fading to white before reducing the height to zero. But the background of the app is black/darkblue.

Is there a way to change the color of this animation?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you maybe add an example at via https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: Did you ever solve this?